# BBGKY Hierarchy for non-pairwise Hamiltonians

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

In all of the derivations of the BBGKY hierarchy (Bogoliubov–Born–Green–Kirkwood–Yvon hierarchy) I have seen, the Hamiltonian is assumed to contain at most pairwise interactions, i.e. terms of the form $U(r_i - r_j)$. Is there a similar procedure or hierarchy for systems where the Hamiltonian is still permutation invariant, but has higher-order interactions, or interactions that can't be decomposed into a set-wise form?